# Jquery inifinte scroll not working after AJAX using Yii infinite scroller extension

Tags: yii, infinite-scroll

Jquery inifinte scroll not working after AJAX using Yii infinite scroller extension. Please see my code below

post.php

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
     {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $total = Post::model()->count();

        $pages = new CPagination($total);
        $pages->pageSize = 20;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        $posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);

        $this->render('index', array(
            'posts' => $posts,
            'pages' => $pages,
        ));
     }
}
```

View.php

```
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/themes/front/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   function Sort(){
$('#LoadingImage').show();
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('index.php/site/Sort')?>',
    data: "",
    success: function(response){
        $("#posts").replaceWith(response);
    },         
});
}
<div id="posts">
 <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
   <div class="post">
      <p>Autor: <?php echo $post->author; ?></p>
      <p><?php echo $post->text; ?></p>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php $this->widget('ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller', array(
    'contentSelector' => '#posts',
    'itemSelector' => 'div.post',
    'loadingText' => 'Loading...',
    'donetext' => 'This is the end... my only friend, the end',
    'pages' => $pages,
 )); ?>
```

So far it works fine and items are loading on scroll.
But I have ajax sorting of posts based on category. Where the posts loads but the infinte scroll is not working?

I have a call to action with renderPartial as follows

```
public function actionSort()
{
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->order = ' id desc';
        $total = Post::model()->count();

        $pages = new CPagination($total);
        $pages->pageSize = 20;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        $posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);

    $this->renderPartial('_index', array(
            'posts' => $posts,
            'pages' => $pages,false,true
        ));
}
```

and my render partial view is as follows
_index.php

```
<div id="posts">
 <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
   <div class="post">
      <p>Autor: <?php echo $post->author; ?></p>
      <p><?php echo $post->text; ?></p>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php $this->widget('ext.yiinfinite-scroll.YiinfiniteScroller', array(
    'contentSelector' => '#posts',
    'itemSelector' => 'div.post',
    'loadingText' => 'Loading...',
    'donetext' => 'This is the end... my only friend, the end',
    'pages' => $pages,
 )); ?>
```

The infinite scroll is not working after AJAX sort
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiinfinite-scroll/

Answer (score -1):

Write this:

```
$this->renderPartial('_index', array(
        'posts' => $posts,
        'pages' => $pages),false,true
    );
```

instead of this :

```
$this->renderPartial('_index', array(
        'posts' => $posts,
        'pages' => $pages,false,true
    ));
```

Comment: What is the use " ) " closing bracket after $pages?